# How to copy commits from one branch to another?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I've got two branches from my master:

- **v2.1**: (version 2) I've been working on for several months
- **wss**: that I created yesterday to add one specific feature to my master (in production)

Is there a way to copy yesterday's commits from wss to v2.1?

Comment: To simply copy commits (or a range of commits) from one branch to another this answer helped me best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491

Comment: [Cherry-Picking specific commits from another branch](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311070225/https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/)

Answer (score 731, accepted):

You should really have a workflow that lets you do this all by merging:

```
- x - x - x (v2) - x - x - x (v2.1)
           \
            x - x - x (wss)
```

So all you have to do is `git checkout v2.1` and `git merge wss`. If for some reason you really can't do this, and you can't use [git rebase](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) to move your wss branch to the right place, the command to grab a single commit from somewhere and apply it elsewhere is [git cherry-pick](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html). Just check out the branch you want to apply it on, and run `git cherry-pick <SHA of commit to cherry-pick>`.

Some of the ways rebase might save you:

If your history looks like this:

```
- x - x - x (v2) - x - x - x (v2.1)
           \
            x - x - x (v2-only) - x - x - x (wss)
```

You could use `git rebase --onto v2 v2-only wss` to move wss directly onto v2:

```
- x - x - x (v2) - x - x - x (v2.1)
          |\
          |  x - x - x (v2-only)
           \
             x - x - x (wss)
```

Then you can merge! If you really, really, *really* can't get to the point where you can merge, you can still use rebase to effectively do several cherry-picks at once:

```
# wss-starting-point is the SHA1/branch immediately before the first commit to rebase
git branch wss-to-rebase wss
git rebase --onto v2.1 wss-starting-point wss-to-rebase
git checkout v2.1
git merge wss-to-rebase
```

Note: the reason that it takes some extra work in order to do this is that it's creating duplicate commits in your repository. This isn't really a good thing - the whole point of easy branching and merging is to be able to do everything by making commit(s) one place and merging them into wherever they're needed. Duplicate commits mean an intent never to merge those two branches (if you decide you want to later, you'll get conflicts).

Comment: Couldn't agree more with this answer. +1. See also my old answer to illustrates the consequences of cherry-picking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for the support, and the extra info on why not to cherry-pick - I know I skimped a little there. @gotgenes: Thanks! I think it's totally worth the effort - just look at the git-rebase manpage. There's no better way to explain it.

Comment: As for why you might be unable to merge - Git merging does not play nice with git-svn. To copy a series of commits from one SVN branch to another, I ended up cherry-picking them and then performing an interactive rebase/reword to remove the incorrect `git-svn-id` references before `dcommit`ing again. Though I probably could have left out the cherry-pick step and just used a rebase by itself.

Comment: Thanks jefromi, this info helped me understand and write this question / answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600066/git-share-pull-request-only-some-commits-with-upstream-repository/32600067#32600067.

Comment: Here's my use case: critical bug fixes were committed to feature branch.  I need it in master to go into production now.  This will save my butt.

Comment: what happen if we have 2 feature branches and for every branch have 4 commits for example and then we want to cherry-pic these 8 commits into master for example.

Comment: I don't get the note at the end. How can making two branches more similar by applying the same changes from a commit introduce conflicts? –

Answer (score 1474):

Use

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

to apply `<commit>` to your **current branch**.

I myself would probably cross-check the commits I pick in `gitk` and cherry-pick them with right-clicks on the commit entry there instead.

---

If you want to go more automatic (with all its dangers) and assuming all commits since yesterday happened on wss you could generate the list of commits using `git log` (with `--pretty` suggested by Jefromi)

```
git log --reverse --since=yesterday --pretty=%H
```

so everything together assuming you use `bash`

```
for commit in $(git log --reverse --since=yesterday --pretty=%H);
do
    git cherry-pick $commit
done
```

If something goes wrong here (there is a lot of potential) you are in trouble since this works on the live checkout, so either do manual cherry-picks or use rebase like suggested by Jefromi.

Comment: All the placeholders for the --pretty option are in the git-log manpage. You can get any format you want - particularly useful for getting the fields you want for a script in an easily parsable form.

Comment: I also would like to point out that, assuming you really do want to create duplicate commits, the method using `git rebase` in my answer is more robust. In particular, using a for loop like this, if one of the cherry-picks fails, it will still try to do all the rest of them. This is... very very not good, let's say.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I never use it, but do it manually. But cherry-pick is still the answer, at least to the question title. I modified the response.

Comment: Someone committed to an old/incorrect branch, and cherry-pick let me put that commit into the right branch (while still keeping them as the committer). Perfect.

Comment: So surprised I've never run across cherry-pick in any of my prior Git readings/lookups.  The hours and hours of work it would have saved me...  I'd multi-upvote this answer if I could!

Comment: I use this successfully by repeating the command for each commit I want to copy over. Essentially the process I use is 1) Checkout using ```git checkout <branch-name> ``` the source branch you're copying from, and ```git log``` the commits and copy the full hashes to a notepad 2) Checkout the target branch you're copying to 3) ```git cherry-pick <hash>``` using the hashes you copied to your notepad 4) repeat step 3 for any other commits you want to copy. If there are issues you'll need to resolve them and ```git cherry-pick --continue``` after resolving them.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Could you please elaborate "I myself would probably cross-check the commits I pick in gitk and cherry-pick them with right-clicks on the commit entry there instead." What do you mean by "cross-check"?  Will cherry-pick prompt me  before importing each file(is there an option for that)? Is there anything that can be done on command line to achieve the same that you do by "right-click"?

Comment: @bitsand  at step 3: Is it possible to use multiple hashes ( e.g.  git cherry-pick hash_n1 hash_n2 hash_n3 ? If not, do you start with most recent hash or oldest hash ?

Comment: @qqqqq I've not used it but you can do `git cherry-pick A^..B` from A-B. A should be older than B.

Comment: Also you can just do `git cherry-pick A C G H`, where letters are any of the commits that you want to apply to the branch (in chronological order)

Answer (score 133):

`git cherry-pick` : Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits

Assume we have branch **A** with (X, Y, Z) commits. We need to add these commits to branch **B**. We are going to use the `cherry-pick` operations.

When we use `cherry-pick`, we should add commits on branch **B** in the same chronological order that the commits appear in Branch **A**.

cherry-pick does support a range of commits, but if you have merge commits in that range, it gets really complicated

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick SHA-COMMIT-X
git cherry-pick SHA-COMMIT-Y
git cherry-pick SHA-COMMIT-Z
```

Example of workflow :

[image]

We can use `cherry-pick` with [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_options)

*-e or --edit* : With this option, git cherry-pick will let you edit the commit message prior to committing.

*-n or --no-commit* : Usually the command automatically creates a sequence of commits. This flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick each named commit to your working tree and the index, without making any commit. In addition, when this option is used, your index does not have to match the HEAD commit. The cherry-pick is done against the beginning state of your index.

Here an interesting article [git cherry-pick: it might not be what you think](https://blog.founddrama.net/2013/07/git-cherry-pick/comment-page-1/) concerning `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 86):

Suppose I have committed changes to the master branch.
I will get the commit id (`xyz`) of the commit now.
Then I have to go to the branch for which I need to push my commits.

Single commit id `xyz`

```
git checkout branch-name
git cherry-pick xyz
git push origin branch-name
```

Multiple commit id's `xyz` `abc` `qwe`

```
git checkout branch-name
git cherry-pick xyz abc qwe
git push origin branch-name
```

Answer (score 40):

The answers already mentioned cover most of the stuff but one thing that seems to be missing is the `--no-commit` feature of `cherry-pick`ing.

Assume, you have more than one commits on the feature branch and you want to "merge" all of them into a single commit and put them on your main branch. In that case what you need to do is:

```
git checkout <branch-on-which-to-add-features>
git cherry-pick --no-commit <commit-hash>
git cherry-pick --no-commit <commit-hash>
.
.
.
```

And finally, once you have `cherry-pick`ed all the required features, you could do a final commit:

```
git commit -m "Some message for the merge commit"
```

Ideally, as [@Cascabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474371/8293309) mentioned, you should be using `merge` or `rebase`. But if you feel there's no other choice, you could get away with using `cherry-pick`ing.

Answer (score 25):

You could [create a patch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) from the commits that you want to copy and [apply the patch](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) to the destination branch.

Comment: Even if you for some reason really want to use patch(es) instead of cherry-pick(s)/rebase, the straightforward way to do it is with `git format-patch <revision range>` and `git am *.patch`.

Comment: It requires `checkout` to another branch.

Answer (score 14):

Or if You are little less on the evangelist's side You can do a little ugly way I'm using. In deploy_template there are commits I want to copy on my master as branch deploy

```
git branch deploy deploy_template
git checkout deploy
git rebase master
```

This will create new branch deploy (I use -f to overwrite existing deploy branch) on deploy_template, then rebase this new branch onto master, leaving deploy_template untouched.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach.

```sh
git checkout {SOURCE_BRANCH}               # switch to Source branch.
git checkout {COMMIT_HASH}                 # go back to the desired commit.
git checkout -b {temp_branch}              # create a new temporary branch from {COMMIT_HASH} snapshot.
git checkout {TARGET_BRANCH}               # switch to Target branch.
git merge {temp_branch}                    # merge code to your Target branch.
git branch -d {temp_branch}                # delete the temp branch.
```

Comment: Feel like this is a really good approach in case you mess things up by resetting your progress and have a separate branch (testing environment in my case) from which you can use to restore your commits from.

Comment: I used this approach to add commits I missed during head resetting. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's safer to use built-in git gui for cherry-picking specific commits:

For ex: copy one commit from `dev` branch to `main` branch:

```
git checkout main
gitk --all
```

And then right-click on desired commit and select `Cherry-pick this commit`

[image]

`gitk` for Mac: [Install gitk on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17582685)

Comment: This answers assumes a particular OS and app install. Can you make it more generic?

Comment: gitk is available for multiple OS. For mac: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17582685

Comment: Could you explain why it is inherently safer to cherry-pick through the UI vs through the CLI?

Answer (score 3):

The cherry-pick command can read the list of commits from the standard input.

The following command cherry-picks commits authored by the user John that exist in the "develop" branch but not in the "release" branch, and does so in the chronological order.

```
git log develop --not release --format=%H --reverse --author John | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Answer (score 2):

For the simple case of just copying the last commit from branch wss to v2.1, you can simply grab the commit id (`git log --oneline | head -n 1`) and do:

```
git checkout v2.1
git merge <commit>
```

Comment: This requires checking out to another branch.