# Install gitk on Mac

Tags: git, macos, osx-mountain-lion, gitk

How can I install gitk on a Mac?

From their official website, it seems gitk comes with Git, but the version of my Git (*git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)*) does not come with gitk.

`brew install gitk` does not work for gitk.

Version information (copied from comments):

- [OS X v10.8.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) (12C2034) (Mountain Lion)
- [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) version 4.6 (4H127)

Comment: what version of osx are you using? On 10.8.4 I have `git version 1.8.2.1 (Apple Git-45)` which includes `gitk`

Comment: Have you installed XCode?

Comment: I installed XCode Version `4.6 (4H127)` and Mac Version `OS X 10.8.2 (12C2034)`

Comment: There's roughly a bajillion Git tools that work on OS X, why do you need `gitk` specifically? Also, `gitk` is included with Homebrew git.

Comment: Thanks @millimoose! Could you please recommend a couple similar tools?

Comment: @Mingyu: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/, for one.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments, and I installed SourceTree, which seems to be a great git client on Mac.

Comment: GitX is a pretty nice Git client. I miss it on Linux

Comment: http://git-scm.com/download/mac download this and install for gitk on macos

Comment: If you installed SourceTree ... it comes with it's own packed-in copy of `git` - and it's a build that has `gitk` in it, so you can create an alias for it and just use it.

Comment: And here's where to find SourceTree's version of git which includes `gitk` as @Adrian mentioned: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html (see "SourceTree file path for Embedded Git")

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Correct, the 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37) does not come with gitk. You can install a more recent version of Git + git-ui as a separate formula by using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable *brew*).  More thorough instructions are located on *[The fastest and easiest way to install Ruby on a Mac in 2022](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)* (see this commit extracting git-gui/gitk into its own formula: *[git-gui: split from git formula.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/dfa3ccf1e7d3901e371b5140b935839ba9d8b706)*)

Run the following commands at the terminal:

```
brew update
brew install git
brew install git-gui
```

If you get an error indicating it could not link Git, then you may need to change permissions/owners of the files it mentions.

Once completed, run:

```
type -a git
```

And make sure it shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

If it does not, run:

```
brew doctor
```

And make the path change to put */usr/local/bin* earlier in the path. Now, gitk should be on your path (along with an updated version of Git).

Comment: I installed git 1.8.3.4 to use brew. But gitk has Bug. If you check out branch and type `gitk --all`, unstaged local branch is visible. After you type git status, unstaged local branch is unvisible. Does anyone experience it?

Comment: I did all the update described above, but the version of git didn't change - I must have already had the most recent version. BUT now I suddenly have gitk! hurray

Comment: Yep same with @Kuba I mysteriously now have gitk!

Comment: It might be necessary to restart the terminal session.

Comment: @giovannipds what was the problem?

Comment: @volvox path was not changing to `/usr/local/bin`, the latest git was installed but not being used and I didn't know to do that manually. I followed what @Leo explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496039/842768 and installing Git again it has installed where it needed.

Comment: What if it's `/usr/bin/git`?

Comment: Even more recent versions of git that comes with MacOS Mojave does not come with gitk: `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`. `brew install git` will install gitk.

Comment: The even more recent formula for `git` has extracted the UI tools and moved them into its own formula: `brew install git-gui`

Comment: Since I already had git installed, there was an error when creating the links on my initial install. I ran `brew link --overwrite git-gui` to force it to use the new one and everything works great now.

Comment: And on Mac M1: arch -arm64 brew install git-gui instead of brew install git-gui

Comment: works for me as of july 2023

Answer (score 49):

The Git Mac version comes without `gitk`, but if you do `brew install git` you get instant access to `gitk`.

I'm using [macOS v10.12.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra).

But this stopped working. You must install `brew install git-gui`

Comment: What versions of Git? Working and not working.

Answer (score 29):

As of [macOS v10.15.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina), I run:

```
brew install git
brew install git-gui
```

And it worked for me.

Comment: FTU of MAC. thanks for the brew. its worth installation I guess.

Comment: "FTU" may be a (double) typo of [FYI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FYI#Phrase).

Comment: brew is like pip to Linux for Mac.

Comment: Its called git-gui and not gitk part of the official git docs: https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score 28):

I just had the same problem and solved it as follows:

1. Download the official Git package for Mac from http://git-scm.com/download/mac
2. Install the package. This places all the binaries in folder */usr/local/git/bin*.
3. Optionally, run the included script to make gitk accessible outside of terminals
4. Either add */usr/local/git/bin* to your PATH or use an alias (`alias gitk='/usr/local/git/bin/gitk'`)

Comment: in ~/.bash_profile file. Add : export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH    or /usr/local/git/bin path.

Answer (score 24):

If you already have Git installed via Homebrew, you can just do upgrade:

```
type -a git
brew upgrade git
type -a git
```

#### Output

> /usr/bin/git 
> /usr/local/bin/git

The one at local/bin will have gitk.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Also, if you have been using the system git that comes with Mac OS X, the sequence to do a new install of git via homebrew would instead be: `brew install git && which git` which (no pun intended!) should give you the output `/usr/local/bin/git`

... Note: I would also *highly* recommend updating and doctoring first, as in: `brew update ; brew doctor && brew install git && which git` -or- `brew update ; brew doctor && brew upgrade git && which git` instead... to get the expected `/usr/local/bin/git` output (from the `which` command).

Comment: @giovannipds - do ***brew install git***
    .you probably have older version of Git.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. I installed GitX instead.

You can install GitX from here:

https://gitx.github.io/

Download the package and install it. After that, open gitk from spotlight search, go to the top left corner. Click on GitX and enable the terminal usage.

Go to your repository and simply type:

```
gitx --all
```

It will open the GUI.

- [Readme](https://github.com/gitx/gitx#readme)
- [User manual](http://gitx.frim.nl/user_manual.html) (Note: This is outdated. Some UI may not look the same.)

Comment: *"GitX, a long-defunct GUI for the Git version-control system"*. Is that right?

Comment: Can also be installed via brew: `brew install --cask gitx`.

Comment: Only GUI tool which worked for me for a large repo (tens of thousands of commits).

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. The Unix way (simple and recommended)
2. The [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) way

**1. Unix Way: In four simple steps**

1. Execute `which git` in the terminal to know the location of your `git` executable. Open that directory & locate `gitk` inside the `bin` folder. Copy the path --- typically `/usr/local/git/bin`
2. Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file to add the location of local `git` & `gitk` in the paths or, simply copy-paste from the sample written below.

Sample `bash_profile`:

```
# Enabling gitk
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

If you don't have a `bash_profile` file and want to learn how to create one, then [click here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99835/how-to-create-bash-profile-and-profile).

3. This step is relevant if you're using [OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan) or higher, and [you run into an unknown color name “lime” error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682208). Locate `gitk` executable (typically at `/usr/local/bin/gitk`), take a backup & open it in a text editor. Find all occurrences of `lime` in the file & replace them with `"#99FF00"`.
4. Reload Bash: `source ~/.bash_profile`

Now, run `gitk`

---

**2. Homebrew way**

*Updates* - If you do not have `homebrew` on your Mac, get it installed first. It may require `sudo` privileges.

- `brew update`
- `brew doctor`
- `brew link git`
- added `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.0/bin` to path, reload Bash, and run `gitk`
- No luck yet? Proceed further.
- Run `which git` and observe if Git is still linked to `/usr/bin/git`
- If yes, then open the directory and locate the was a binary executable.
- Take its backup. It may be save with a name **git.bak** and delete the original file
- Reload the terminal - `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: brew should NOT need sudo privileges. The brew installation procedure itself needs sudo, but it then opens permissions on /usr/local so that after that you wont need sudo. If you need sudo, either you're choosing that you want brew to only work with sudo (totally understandable decision), or you've missed a step in the installation procedure.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. TBH `gitk` not working is a really annoying problem & failing to launch it because they forgot to `sudo` at some random step is the last thing I'd wished anyone reading this ever faced. I wrote it to play it safe (tho, sudo isn't).

Answer (score 4):

You can also get `gitk` with the `git` from [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts).

```
sudo port install git
```

Comment: A now-deleted "answer" warns against using sudo. Why is it necessary?

Answer (score 4):

For [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) users, I found [this page very useful](http://effectif.com/git/making-gitk-look-good-on-mac), particularly this suggestion:

```
/usr/bin/wish $(which gitk)
```

...without that, the window did not display correctly!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing `brew info git`.

Which gave me info that Git was cloned into: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.0

So I just added: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.0/bin to the beginning of my PATH environment variable.

Note: I don't know how to use Homebrew... I just want to get going quickly as I have other things to do... this basically gets gitk running for me, so I'm sticking to it for now (it is probably not the way to work with Homebrew though).

Comment: `brew info git` and then adding the path it is in to PATH in ~/.profile worked for me (y)

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to already have Fink installed, this worked for me on OS X v10.10.5 (Yosemite):

`fink install git`

Note that as a side effect, other Git commands are also using the newer Git version (2.5.1) installed by Fink, rather than the version from Apple (2.3.2), which is still there, but preempted by my $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check which version of Git you are running. The one installed with Homebrew should be running on */usr/local/bin/git*. You can verify this from a terminal using:

```
which git
```

In case Git shows up on a different directory, you need to run this from a terminal to add it to your path:

```
echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that, you can close and open again your terminal or just run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And voilà! In case you are running on [OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) you might need to install XQuartz.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac 10.7.5 with Git version 1.7.12.4.

When I ran *gitk*, I got an error:

> "Error in startup script: expected version number but got "Git-37)"
> while executing 
> "package vcompare $git_version "1.6.6.2"" 
> invoked from within 
> "if {[package vcompare $git_version "1.6.6.2"] >= 0} { 
> set show_notes "--show-notes"  
> }" 
> (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 11587)

When I looked at the code in gitk I saw the line that sets the version.

```
set git_version [join [lrange [split [lindex [exec git version] end] .] 0 2] .]
```

This somehow parsed the **git version** results to `Git-37` instead of `1.7.12.4`

I just replaced the *git_version* line with:

```
set git_version "1.7.12.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you have [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) installed, but want to use `gitk` as well, you can use the version that comes with Sourcetree's embedded version of Git.

Sourcetree's [version of Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html) (and thus gitk) is here:

For Windows:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\git.exe

or

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin
```

For Mac:

```
/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/bin
```

In that directory, you'll find a `gitk` executable.

Thanks to @Adrian for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582685/install-gitk-on-mac#comment92583426_17582685) which alerted me to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Run the following commands at the terminal:**

1. brew update
2. brew install git
3. brew install git-gui

Comment: This duplicates the accepted answer. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.