# gitk will not start on Mac: unknown color name "lime"

Tags: gitk

I've installed git on a mac via `brew install git`. When I try to start gitk I get the following error:

```
Error in startup script: unknown color name "lime"
    (processing "-fore" option)
    invoked from within
"$ctext tag conf m2 -fore [lindex $mergecolors 2]"
    (procedure "makewindow" line 347)
    invoked from within
"makewindow"
    (file "/usr/local/bin/gitk" line 12434)
```

It appears that my Mac doesn't have a color named `lime`.

Can I add a lime color to the environment, or is there a better fix?

The git version is 2.7.0, and the Mac is running Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can check your version of Tcl/Tk by running `wish` and using the command `info patchlevel`. It appears that git 2.7.0, Tcl/Tk 8.5.9, and OS X 10.11 El Capitan do not work well together.

I solved this problem by doing `brew cask install tcl`, which installed 8.6.4, and `gitk` works now.

Comment: There's something odd using MacPorts here. Tcl version 8.6.4 is installed, but wish is reporting 8.5.9.

Comment: Once I installed a new Tcl/Tk, I had to do `brew install --build-from-source  git` in order to get `git gui` to start `gitk` with the updated Tcl.

Comment: A caveat I've since discovered: if you have tcl 8.6.4 installed, then `rbenv` has trouble installing new Ruby versions.

Comment: `brew cask install tcl` is currently giving me a Ruby error `undefined method 'default_spec_cache_dir' for Gem:Module` :/ Fortunately, Konrad's answer below works in the meantime.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (on El Capitan): "brew cask install tcl" installs 8.5.9, not 8.6.4, so the error remains. Konrad's workaround fixed the problem until this can maybe work.

Comment: Make sure you `brew update` to make sure you have the latest version information. Beyond that, I don't know why I'd get 8.6.4 and someone else would get a different version.

Comment: didn't work for me. El Capitan 10.11.4. Replacing "lime" as suggested in following answer by Konrad worked.

Comment: My gitk also didn't work from gui, so I followed the tip from @lo5an, but first I had to `brew uninstall git`

Comment: I installed Tcl 8.6 without brew, by downloading the [ActiveTcl installer package](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). Gitk works fine now.

Comment: i installed tcl 8.6.4.1 successfully with brew cask but `info patchlevel` still shows `8.5.9` after install. what am I missing?

Comment: Well here is the answer to my previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129498/idle-warns-against-an-old-tcl-version-even-though-ive-installed-a-newer-version

Comment: actually `tclsh` now gives `8.6.4` but `wish` still gives `8.5.9` and I still get the lime error when trying to run `gitk`

Comment: If I try to run `brew cask install tcl` within the wish command line I get the following error: invalid command name "brew"

Comment: @mrbela: Did you get the solution

Comment: @SagarTrehan no, sorry.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The updated tcl is probably installed under `/usr/local/bin`, whereas the previous tcl binary is under `/usr/bin`. You can verify this by running `$ whereis wish`. The workaround for is to prioritize `/usr/local/bin` in my `bashrc` by setting `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. After this, `gitk` works.

Comment: I got "Warning: A Cask for tcl is already installed." and even after reinstalling tcl, gitk still not working: "brew cask reinstall tcl"

Comment: @Malik you need to install homebrew

Answer (score 49):

I also found the same problem with exactly the same version of git and OSX. As a temporary workaround I suggest you to do the following:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/gitk /usr/local/bin/gitk.bkp
vi /usr/local/bin/gitk
```

and replace all occurences of lime to any color you want (I used #99FF00). Here is the vim command:

```
:%s/lime/"#99FF00"/g
```

EDIT:
Please follow Keith B answer for permanent fix.

Comment: I had to change the hex code to "green" to get it to work, it failed on line 3400 otherwise.

Comment: Using MacPorts this file was located in `/opt/local/bin/gitk`

Comment: I had the same problem on ubuntu 12.04 after updating git/gitk to version 2.7.0. I have tcl 8.5.0. and no update is available in the standard ubuntu 12 repos, so this workaround was the solution in my context.

Comment: @Konrad: Thank you! For anyone else on OSX, 1liner replace: `sed -i.lime_color_replace_backup 's/lime/"#99FF00"/g' /usr/local/bin/gitk`

Comment: you might need to `chmod u+w /usr/local/bin/gitk` beforehand

Comment: My gitk file was actually in /usr/local/git/bin/ Also to save a read-only file do this in vi
:w !sudo tee %

Comment: Works great on `MacOS Sierra`

Comment: usr/local/bin/gitk already has "#99FF00" instead of lime.
but still getting error mentioned in question.

Answer (score 9):

@Konrad Thanks for the help!! Although the answer is correct, please be aware that your command

```
:%s/lime/"#99FF00”/g
```

contains two different quotation marks, which will def. throw an error if copied & pasted.

So in order to go through with it, I had to do:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/gitk /usr/local/bin/gitk.bkp
vi /usr/local/bin/gitk
```

And inside vim:

```
:%s/lime/"#99FF00"/g
```

Comment: I discovered this too. I have enough karma that I was able to edit Konrad's answer.

Comment: I agree. This should have been an edit of Konrad's answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `Caskroom`, follow this:

```bash
$ brew install tcl-tk
$ brew link tcl-tk --force
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks. I had to use `link tcl-tk --force --overwrite` though.

Answer (score 4):

I was face same issue in ubuntu system. Then i flow below step to resolve issue.

1. open /usr/bin/gitk file in any text editor
2. search 'lime' keyword in file
3. replace 'lime' to 'green' with all in file
4. save file changes
5. try again gitk then it works

Answer (score 2):

Useful addition to the good answers suggesting replacing all occurrences of the word "lime" by the word "green" in the file /usr/bin/gitk or /usr/local/git/bin/gitk:

The replacement of occurrences of "lime" in the above "gitk" file is sometimes not enough.

You also need to do the same replacement process on the file `~/.config/git/gitk`, or remove that file.

Answer (score 2):

I am running MAC with Yosemetti and followed the below steps to resolve.

```
open /usr/local/git/bin/gitk file in any text editor

search 'lime' keyword in file

replace 'lime' to 'green' with all in file

save file changes

try again gitk then it works
```

Thanks @kaushal sharma, followed your answer, with a change in the gitk path.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions above, but additionally do the following:

before running vi:
chmod +w /usr/local/bin/gitk

after closing vi:
chmod -w /usr/local/bin/gitk

Comment: Please note that "above" has no context in answers, since they can be sorted in various ways. It would be better to link directly to the answer to which you are referring.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your path is set correctly when trying Keith B's solution. Running `brew doctor` showed, that I had /usr/bin before /usr/local/bin.

```
~ $ brew doctor
...
Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks Konrad ,It work for me with below step

1. sudo brew update
2. sudo brew cask install tcl

-

Comment: It was Kieth B who suggested doing that.