# Can't use gitk when sshing from a specific machine: unkown color 'lime'

Tags: ssh, gitk

When I ssh into a server foo from machine1, I'm able to use gitk fine.  Now I login (`ssh -X` each time) from  machine2 (older version of Suse), and I get the error

```
"unkown color name 'lime'"
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`open /usr/local/git/bin/gitk file in any text editor`

`search 'lime' keyword in file`

`replace 'lime' to 'green' with all in file`

`save file changes`

`try again gitk then it works`

Can also follow my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362856/2850801