# Error running gitk on macOS 10.12.6

Tags: macos, homebrew, gitk

I installed brew and gitk as indicated in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582685/install-gitk-on-mac). I'm running on macOS 10.12.6. git still works fine, but when I try to run gitk from the terminal, I get:

```
Error in startup script: osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
    while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
        end te..."
    invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
    exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes ..."
    (file "/usr/local/bin/gitk" line 12212)
```

I did try restarting the terminal session and reinstalling git with brew.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: same problem here running mac 10.13.4

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this could be caused by an old Quark scripting addition?

https://github.com/svg/svgo-osx-folder-action/issues/5

Removing said folder works for me.

```
sudo rm -rf QXPScriptingAdditions.osax/
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to terminal
2. su
3. Change directory and run ls:

   $ cd /Library/ScriptingAdditions 
   $ ls
   Adobe Unit Types.osax
4. Remove or move the directory:
   mv  Adobe\ Unit\ Types.osax /tmp

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error is related to any scripts within the `/Library/ScriptingAdditions` folder that are incompatible with your current MacOS version.

The error will generally name this script, `WebexScriptAddition.osax` in my case, `Adobe Unit Types.osax` in Pawel's case, and `QXPScriptingAdditions.osax` in Daniel's case.

The solution is the same in every case as both have outlined: either delete the script or move it to a temp location, test your system, then delete the temp location where you saved the script earlier.