# gitk shows blank in mac os Catalina

Tags: macos, gitk

my system is
macOS Catalina  10.15.7 (19H2)

I installed git via brew, below shows the version installed

```
git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

and the version for git-gui is  `2.30.0`

when i type `gitk`, in either iterm2, or the ios builtin terminal app, they all just show blank

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814988/4582240 to try to update the git, hoping it would do some magic, but it did not.

Please help on this.

Comment: I decided to use sourceTree, and also install the sourceTree command line tool instead. It works fine on mac. but I will keep this question open and curious about the solutions.

Comment: “I installed git via brew” Actually no. You are using Apple’s Git, not the one from brew.

Comment: @matt, it now shows different result after used 'brew upgrade git-gui'
```git --version
git version 2.30.0```

Comment: Cool! How is the gitk now?

Comment: It works now. @matt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me after I did `brew upgrade git-gui`