# Uploading an existing source to Bitbucket

Tags: php, git, laravel-4, bitbucket

Okay here's the overview. There's a Laravel 4.0 project in Bitbucket. I want to update this to version 4.1 so a Branch was created. I downloaded the Branch, but **did not** do the changes to that Branch. I kept is in a separate folder, downloaded a fresh new copy of Laravel 4.1 and moved the necessary files from the 4.0 Branch to the fresh 4.1 source. And changed the config settings as well.

Now I want to commit this fresh project back. Can someone please tell me if its possible to upload the fresh 4.1 project as a brand new Branch? If so how to do it?

I have downloaded the SourceTree as well. If you can tell me how to do it through the GUI, its even better. Either way is fine though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use cherry-pick or rebase:
[How to copy commits from one branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474353/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-branch-to-another)

or rename your branch with:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
```

and push this with:

```
git push origin your_branch_name -f
```

---

you can go to an existent branch and get your commits from another branch using `git cherry-pick commit-hash-here`, or if your changes are not commited, you can stash your changes using `git stash` and unstashing the changes in the other branch (executing `git stash pop`)

Are you asking for that?