# How to copy a commit in another branch without any change?

Tags: git

Assume that we have master branch, and commit a0->a1->a2->a3.
And in commit a1, we make another branch called dev: a1->b2->b3, that is:

```
a0->a1->a2->a3 (master)
     -->b2->b3 (dev)
```

And a3 is quite different from b3, means that they have a lot of conflicts.

What I want is in master branch, I want to get b3 without any change, like below:
a0->a1->a2->a3->b3 (master)

How to do with git command?
Thanks!

**More:** I mean to ignore a3 entirely. In some case, you know b3 is good enough, and a3 fails. So just take b3 completely.

Comment: so you want to ignore commit a3 entirely? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, ignore a3 entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy commits from one branch to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474353/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-branch-to-another)

Comment: Easiest solution is to just revert a3 and then merge your dev branch back into your master

Comment: There will be conflicts to solve? I want a solution without handling any conflict, just take b3 there in master branch.

Comment: Do you care about `a2` and `a3` at all?

Comment: depends if a2 has conflicts with b2. simply reverting a3 (ignoring anything in it) and then merging b3 into master would essentially be fast-forwarding the branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a clear distinction here between these entities:

- a *commit*, with author / committer name, email, and message;
- the *source tree* associated with any given commit;
- the commit *graph* (some or all of the DAG); and
- a *branch name* like `master` or `dev`.

Remember, each commit has a complete source tree attached: a snapshot, as it were, of the work tree at the time the commit was made.  In some ways this is the most important part, but it's what we will talk about last, because the commits and graph are in the way.

Each commit also has a pointer back to its parent commit(s).  This is where there's a slight problem with the graph fragment you've drawn: the pointers are pointing the wrong way ("forwards" in time, from oldest to newest, instead of backwards, newest to oldest).

Let's redraw the graph fragment with the arrows going the correct way:

```
a0 <- a1 <- a2 <- a3   <-- master
       ^
        `-- b2 <- b3   <-- dev
```

None of these commits can be changed.  Commit `b3` points back to `b2`, and `b2` points back to `a1`, and so on.  (More precisely, each commit has, stored in it, the SHA-1 IDs of its parent(s).  At this level, a merge is simply a commit with at least two parent IDs.)

The *names*, in this case `master` and `dev`, *can* be changed.  All they have is a pointer to (more precisely, the SHA-1 ID of) a single starting-point commit: in this case, `a3` and `b3` respectively.  These are the *newest* commits on the branches.

The graph itself is formed by taking these starting-points and following all the commit parent-pointers.  That's how we get the picture above: `master` points us to `a3`, `dev` points us to `b3`, and we combine `a3` and `b3` and all their parent ID pointers.

What's missing from this drawing is the *source* associated with each commit.  I left it out for two good reasons: (1) I don't have it, only you have it and (2) it won't fit anyway. :-)  But from what you've said above, it sounds like the source tree associated with commit `a3` is essentially worthless.

You have not said anything about the source trees associated with commits `a2` and `b2`.  What should we make of those?

---

With all those mentioned, let's look at what you can do.  You can't *change* a commit, but you can make a *copy* that's "almost the same" and therefore "just as good".<sup>1</sup>  You can also change branch pointers arbitrarily.  But note that if you make copies of commits, everyone who's sharing this repository (or a `--bare` copy of it) needs to get those copies, and if you change a branch-pointer in ways they don't expect, it makes things more difficult for them.

Let's take a look, then, at things people *do* expect.

They expect branches to "grow", i.e., acquire new commits that point back to existing commits.  If `master` grew a new commit `a4` that pointed back to `a3`, that would be entirely unsurprising, for instance.

They expect new branch names to appear: `feature3` might suddenly come into existence, pointing either to some existing commit (perhaps to `a1` or `b2`).

They occasionally even expect branch names to vanish, usually after that branch got merged into some other branch.

What they don't expect, at least not without some advance warning, is for branches to "shrink": for a branch name to point to a commit that used to be only in its history.  For instance, if we were to completely discard commit `a3` we'd have this drawing:

```
a0 <- a1 <- a2   <-- master
       ^
        `-- b2 <- b3   <-- dev
```

Note that you *can* do this!  It's just that people don't expect it—and those other people who are sharing this repository might, and very easily can, put `a3` back.  It *will* happen by accident,<sup>2</sup> without them even thinking about it, if they're not prepared for this kind of branch rewinding.  (I have personal experience with this from something about 7 years ago.  We wound up putting in a "reject certain commits by SHA-1 ID" hack in the bare repo pre-receive hook.)

So, now you must decide whether you want to "rewind `master`" to make it look like commit `a3` is gone.  If you do this, make sure everyone sharing the repository knows about it, lest they accidentally re-introduce it.  Then simply re-set `master` to point to `a2`, i.e., change the arrangement so that `a2` is the newest history for `master`.

It's probably better *not* to do this rewinding, precisely because of the problems that this sort of rewind causes with sharing.  You said (I think) that you wanted to discard the changes made between `a2` and `a3`, though, and this is where we get into the *source tree* attached to a commit.

Suppose that instead of removing `a3`, we added a new `a4` that had the *same* source tree as `a2`?

If we didn't have git at all—if, for instance, we just saved each tree somewhere, as a back-up copy, with a name and date on it—there are two ways we could do that:

1. undo everything in the work-tree: wherever a line was added, remove it; wherever a line was removed, restore it; wherever a word was changed, change it back; or
2. just restore the work-tree from the saved back-up copy.

With git, we have the same two options, because each commit has a saved back-up copy of the entire tree.

Method (1), undoing everything, can be difficult if you don't have git, but it's really easy with git as it's a basic operation: `git revert`.  (Method 2 is *not* built-in, as we'll see.)

This is where we get into the fact that git stores content.  I mentioned above that, in some ways, this is the most important part of what git does.  This is because everything else git does—managing the commit graph and commit messages, so as to remember who did what, when, and why—only matters once you have some content.

Git differs from many other systems, though, in that each commit stores a complete tree.  In other systems, each commit stores changes; this is not the case in git.

This means, however, that in order to *see* changes, you must direct git to look at *two* commits.<sup>3</sup>  But `git revert` takes a single commit ID.  This is where the commit *graph* comes in: `revert` can compare that commit's source tree to its parent commit's source tree.

In this case, for instance, it would make a lot of sense to revert commit `a3`.  To do this, git simply compares `a3` against its parent, `a2`.  Whatever it took to turn `a2` into `a3`—adding some lines, deleting some lines, maybe even adding or deleting entire files—git can simply reverse these changes.  If you apply this "reverse change" to the source tree from `a3` and make a new commit `a4`, git guarantees that the source tree for the new `a4` is the same as the one for `a2`.

You might ask why we do this instead of the simpler "copy tree from `a2`".  In this particular case, they would both do the same thing.  But suppose we already had a commit `a4` that was a good commit?  If we copied the tree from `a2` to make `a5`, we'd lose the changes in `a4` (vs `a3`).  But if, instead, we reverse `a3`'s changes while keeping `a4`'s, we get a new `a5` that is "`a2`, plus `a3`, plus `a4`, minus `a3`".  With luck, the plus and minus cancel each other out and `a5` is `a2 plus a4`, as it were.

Let's draw that:

```
a0 <- a1 <- a2 <- a3 <- a4   <-- master
       ^
        `-- b2 <- b3   <-- dev
```

where `a4` is the revert of `a3`.  This leaves the source tree in `a4` the same as that in `a2`: if you ran `git diff <id-of-a2> master`, there would be no diff shown.  The two commits are different—their SHA-1 IDs are different, their messages are different, their parent SHA-1 IDs are different—but their *source trees* are the same.

Moreover, anyone sharing from this repository sees the kind of commit-graph change they expect: `master` grew a new commit `a4`.

You can now combine changes from the `dev` branch any way you like (cherry-pick and merge being the two common methods, though these two do very different things, both in terms of the source trees, and in terms of the commit graph).

Alternatively, you can `rewind` master back to `a2`, after which you can combine changes from `dev` any way you like.  In terms of the resulting *source tree*, you will get exactly the same results.  In terms of the *commit graph*, you won't have commit `a3` any more, nor will you have its reversion commit `a4` (which you won't need).  Someone who look at your repository in the future will never see the malfunctioning `a3` nor its revert, since it will be as if they never existed.  But anyone sharing the repository, who already has `a3`, will need to do their own extra work to handle the "rewinding" of `master` (basically they also need to discard their `a3`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether it really *is* "just as good" depends on what you're using it for, and how good a job you did copying it.

<sup>2</sup>This is less likely once you've added a new commit, but it's still possible.  It remains easy to have it happen accidentally if your users do merges, and generally gets harder if you force them to rebase.

<sup>3</sup>Two or more, really, but it gets more complicated when dealing with more than two commits.  Also, git can work with just a tree (or the index) rather than a complete commit.