# which git commands should i choose to synchronize only one row?

Tags: git, github

i am a cs student and i have got a question from my homework

A and B work on the same module. A works on A-Branch, B works on B-Branch.

A Branch:

> 1. a = 1
> 2. b = 2
> 3. //Number of cats
> 4. c = 1
> 5. //Number of dogs
> 6. d = 42

B Branch:

> 1. a = 1
> 2. b = 2
> 3. //Number of cats
> 4. c = 2
> 5. //Number of dogs
> 6. d = 42

B wants to apply this setting in 4th row("c=2" ->"c=1") to his file. But he just wants to take only this row, not the whole file or other files. what should  A und B do?

Comment: IMHO stackoverflow isn't the place to ask your homework questions

Comment: Agreeing with @naveenmarri on this. As this question isn't related to real-world programming, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: i am just honest to tell my situation. but thank your advice

Comment: still looking forwards someone' answer, thank all

Comment: @lee This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474353/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-branch-to-another

Answer (score 0):

B should commit his changes to his B-branch and ask A to pull from B-branch.

Comment: which commad then？ "git commit " will commit the whole file not the single row

Comment: use git add -p 
which allows you to select hunks interactively