# Gir branch to branch retrofit

Tags: git

I am writing a shell script to automate code retrofit between two different Git branches. The requirement is I get a list of Git commits(which I have stored in a database table) from one branch and replay those changes on the other branch, and for that I am using Git Cherry-Pick command as below.

```
git checkout target_branch
<Sql command to get commit list> | xargs git cherry-pick
```

The above fails altogether if there are conflicts while picking any of the commits, and I need to implement the following logic using a seperate parameter as input to the script

```
-> if parameter value is Abort, list the files for which conflicts occured while cherry picking and then clean the repo(i am using git reset --merge for cleaning)
-> if parameter value is Overwrite, overwrite the conflicting files with the version of the commit hash
```

I have tried many options, but the only thing left is to create a dummy branch by cherry picking only those commits and then merge the dummy with target, but I don't know how to create a new branch by cherry picks only.

Please suggest a way.

Thanks.
Kumarjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to create a new branch by cherry picks only.

Considering a [cherry-pick is applied on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474430/6309), you could:

- first create the new branch

  ```
  git checkout -b aNewBranch
  ```
- the apply your cherry-picks as usual.

Comment: Which branch should i create the new branch from? If its the target branch, would it be same as cherry picking into the target?