# How do I move a piece of code from one commit to another without using an external editor(all in git)

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Let's say I pulled from a repo and realized that I would have much rather had a piece of code in one commit than the one it currently finds itself in. How do I move said piece of code from that commit to the other without opening an external editor(using git)?

Comment: Pushed commits or local commits not pushed yet? Pushed commits would need rewriting of history to achieve this which is probably one of the most destructive actions you can take in git.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy commits from one branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474353/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-branch-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your changes you may want to use [interactive rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase). This will allow you to edit each commit chronologically.