# Git branch issue (bitbucket)

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, branch, git-branch

Why does a git branch include other branch changes when making a pull request?

So we have 2 main branches namely staging and master on our repository, the flow is we will create a branch-topic for testing and will make a pull request to the staging branch and after that to master branch.

When I create a new branch (branch-topic-100) and finished testing, I would make a pull request to the staging branch but somehow I included the changes from another branch (branch-topic-95) and when I create a new branch again, this branch (branch-topic-95) is always included when I create a pull request to the staging branch.
it's like (branch-topic-95) affects other branches.

What do i need to do to fix this issue when creating a pull request to the staging branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703820/7976758 found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Old+commits+in+pull-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have merged your **Topic-95** branch with the staging. That's why your changes are shown in the **Staging** *environment*.