git merge changes after previous merge
I have worked on a branch, and successfully merged my changes. After that I did another commit and want to merge it as well. However when I create pull request, it offers to merge the whole branch and resolve conflicts with, essentially, my own changes. Can I merge only the commit after already happened merge, not the whole branch?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700983/how-to-keep-a-github-prs-code-separate-from-other-branchs-pr-code , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Old+commits+in+pull-request

Sounds like you are squash-mergingm. Is that the case?


However when I create pull request, it offers to merge the whole branch and resolve conflicts with, essentially, my own changes.

This happens if the commit IDs differ on the PR's target branch from the commit IDs on your source branch. There are multiple ways this can happen:

When completing the PR, you used a Squash Merge, or a Rebase (either with --ff or semi-linear-merge)
Locally, you rewrote the commits on your branch, perhaps by amending or rebasing.

When you create a Pull Request, any commit ID on the source branch that is not present in the target branch will be shown in the list of commits to be merged. Note the view in the PR is not necessarily showing you what the end state will look like. (Because in your case some of the changes being shown are already there, and so they will just have no effect.)

Can I merge only the commit after already happened merge, not the whole branch?

Let's suppose you have branches called: feature and main. In your scenario you merged feature into main (perhaps with a squash merge), and let's call the HEAD of feature at that time<last-feature-commit-merged>. After that you continued working on feature and have more commits. To rewrite your branch, you could use an advanced (onto) rebase, like this:
git fetch
git rebase <last-feature-commit-merged> feature --onto origin/main

After the rebase, force push your branch: git push --force-with-lease origin feature, and then your PR will look how you expect it to.

git checkout your-branch
git rebase main
git add <file>
git rebase --continue
git push origin your-branch --force


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You likely had a squash merge. Create a new branch from your target branch and cherry pick your commit:
git checkout yourtargetbranch
git branch somenewbranch
git checkout somenewbranch
git push -u origin somenewbranch
git cherry-pick <some hash here>

Test, create PR.
