# Git workflow for repository partially synced across master and gh-pages?

Tags: git, github, workflow

I have a repository on GitHub with a `master` branch and a `gh-pages` branch. To make changes, I have been branching off the `master`, making a series of commits, and then merging them into the master when I am satisfied with the changes. The `gh-pages` branch corresponds to a website that demos the project. After the changes have been merged into `master`, I merge them into `gh-pages` and update the `index.html` accordingly.

This current workflow has been fine up until now, but I am now trying to keep the `master` and `gh-pages` branches cleaner. For instance, when I merge `master` onto `gh-pages` to update the `css` file, I don't want the `CONTRIBUTING.md` file to also be carried over to that branch. It only belongs on the `master` branch. Similarly, if I am to merge changes to `index.html` from `gh-pages` to `master`, I don't want the `CNAME` file, for example, to be carried over.

Essentially, I have two branches on which contain a number of files that I would like to keep in sync, but also respectively contain files that are exclusively their own. Is there a better workflow that I could be using to keep these main files in sync while maintaining their distinct files?

---

**Edit:** This question asked another way would be: how do open source projects like [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and [React](https://github.com/facebook/react) keep the source code (`lib`,`dist`,etc.) synced across branches while other files only appear (and are maintained) in one or the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syncing two GIT branches that only differ by a couple of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461224/syncing-two-git-branches-that-only-differ-by-a-couple-of-files)